# JavaScript Regex Combination

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi Stack Overflow,

```
I have this three regexp:
var regex = new RegExp(/[A-Z]+/g); // This is to select only word with CAPS
var regexOk = new RegExp(/[^OK]+/g); // This is to select anything beside OK
var regexDmv = new RegExp(/[^DMV]+/g); // This is to select anything beside DMV

// And a variable: 
var string = "Let's go to the DMV tomorrow, is that OK? ANSWER ME!";
```

Basically what I want to do is to search this string, so that it returns
['ANSWER', 'ME']

Can anyone give me suggestion?

Comment: `[^OK]` matches anything that's not an `O` or a `K`. The same thing with the DMV one. Do you just want what's after the `?`? If so, that's much easier and you should ask that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A. To Match `ANSWER` and `ME` separately (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fK3zC7))**

```
\b(?!DMV|OK)[A-Z]+\b
```

This is the same as `(?!DMV|OK)\b[A-Z]+\b` (you can place the opening boundary `\b` before or after the negative lookahead).

Using Javascript:

```
var regex = /\b(?!DMV|OK)[A-Z]+\b/;
var match = regex.exec(string);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[0];
}
```

**How it works**

- The `[A-Z]+` matches an upper-case word
- The boundaries `\b` on each side of the uppercase letters ensure we have a whole word, not some letters embedded in another word
- The negative lookahead `(?!DMV|OK)` before the word ensures that the word we match is neither `OK` nor `DMV`

**B. To Match `ANSWER ME` together (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/oG2lA0))**

```
(?:\b(?!DMV|OK)[A-Z]+\b\s*)+
```

Again, you can move the opening `\b` if you prefer it before the `[A-Z]+`

In JavaScript:

```
var regex = /(?:\b(?!DMV|OK)[A-Z]+\b\s*)+/;
var match = regex.exec(string);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[0];
}
```

**How it works**

- The `(?:...)+` non-capturing group matches one or more upper-case words `[A-Z]+` followed by optional whitespace characters `\s*`
- The boundaries `\b` on each side of the uppercase letters ensure we have a whole word, not some letters embedded in another word
- The negative lookahead `(?!DMV|OK)` before each word ensures that the word we match is neither `OK` nor `DMV`

Comment: Good, but the answer could be improved by adding a bit of explanation as to what's going on here. There's some saying about a man and a fish...

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am still trying to understand your explanation. But the demo is really helpful.

Comment: Thank you, definitely helpful.  How do I refresh the question?

Comment: @user122652 If you are looking at it now, you are probably looking at the latest version. :) By "refresh" I meant hitting the F5 key on your keyboard, or something like that, to reload the page.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `NOT string` operator in regex. `[^OK]` means any character besides `O` and `K`. You can just do

```
/ANSWER|ME/
```

Comment: I am actually trying to find words that have all CAPS beside OK and DMV